# Pattern using loops in c programming

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int i,j,n;
printf("enter n value\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    for(j=n;j<=i;j--)
    {
        if((i/j==1))
        printf("j");
        else
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

What is the mistake in this code?
I want to print pattern like this

```
     1
    21
   321
  4321
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What do you get instead? What input do you provide? How should your algorithm filter only these numbers? Please explain how you think this should work.

Comment: Side note: Never use `scanf` or other I/O functions without checking the return value.

Comment: Learning how [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) works would probably be a helping thing too. I seriously doubt `printf("j");` is doing what you want it to. Read your docs. The basics of `printf` will literally be one of the first things in any remedial C text.

Comment: @Gerhardh, I agree, but isn't that a bit much for a complete beginner?

Comment: @Manikanta k How is the outputted string literal "j" related with numbers 1, 2, 3, 4?

Comment: `for(j=n;j<=i;j--)`, when `i` is same as `n`, this is infinite loop. Other times loop will not be executed at all

Comment: @Elliott I assume you mean my comment about `scanf`. Well, you cannot start early enough to fight bad habbits. From the number of questions at SO where the scanned value is confused with the return value or where uninitialized values are used because a failing function call was ignored, that lesson is important especially for beginners. It prevents lots of weird problems.

Answer (score 1):

`printf("j");` doesn't print the value of your variable `j`. It just prints a 'j'.

Further your loop condition and your if-statement is wrong.

Try like:

```
for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
    for(j=n; j>0; j--)
    {
        if((j<=i))
            printf("%d", j);  // Print the value of variable j
        else
            printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The pattern only makes sense when `n` is in the range 1..9 so your code should check that. Then the code can also be written like:

```
assert(n >= 1 && n <= 9);   // Fail if n is invalid
char str[10] = "         "; // 9 spaces

str[n] = '\0';              // Terminate the string at position n
for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
    str[n-i] = i + '0';     // Insert i as a character at correct position
    puts(str);              // Print the string plus a newline
}
```

This way you do it with a single loop (and fewer function calls for printing) so the program logic is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach would be to not check if you should print spaces or numbers inside the loop. You know that it should start with 0 or more spaces, so just print them first, them go on printing the numbers.

Also, check that `scanf` succeeds.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("enter n value\n");
    if(scanf("%d", &n) == 1) { // checking that scanf succeeds

        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            // print n-i number of spaces:
            printf("%*s", n - i, "");

            // print the numbers:
            for(int j = i; j >= 1; --j) {
                printf("%d", j);           // Note: Not printf("j");
            }

            putchar('\n');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void  printPattern(int size)
{
    for(int num = 1; num <= size; num++)
    {
        for(int space = 1; space <= size - num; space++)
            printf(" ");
        for(int digit = num; digit >= 1; digit--)
            printf("%d", digit);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    printPattern(4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This should work.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i,j,n;
    int spaceCounter;
    
    printf("enter n value\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        spaceCounter = 0;
        for(j=n; j >= 1; j--)
        {
            if (spaceCounter < (n - i)) {
                printf(" ");
            } else {
                printf("%d", j);    
            }
            spaceCounter++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight issue in your logic formation.
I have made some changes to your code. This should work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i,j,n;
    printf("enter n value\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=n;j>=1;j--)
        {
            if(j<=i)
                printf("%d", j);
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, check the syntax for printf() function. Here %d is a placeholder for an integer variable. You can find out more about placeholders in C at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/format-specifiers-in-c/